# Json ответ разобрать

Tags: java, android, json

Можно ли разобрать циклом массив объектов data. Все объекты имеют внутри одинаковую структуру. То есть использовать для разбора один класс. А не создавать для каждого объекта свой класс

[image: Ответ Json]

Comment: можно. Итерируйте сквозь него и берите значения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, то этот ответ подходит для вас [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13573965/6796460)

Вам нужно использовать итератор

```
Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
String key = iter.next();
try {
    Object value = json.get(key);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // Something went wrong!
  }
}
```

В *value* будет находится ваш объект, который вы можете преобразовать в вашу модель с помощью JsonParser. На примере этого кода

```
String mJsonString = "...";
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser(); 
JsonElement mJson =  parser.parse(mJsonString);

MyDataObject object = gson.fromJson(mJson, MyDataObject.class);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё работает) И код чистый

Answer (score 1):

Альтернативный метод. Можно вообще класс не создавать. Ну если надо создать, то можно просто вместо массива класть в переменные класса

```
//News_list - is ArrayList
                String output = null;
                output = your Json string;
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(output);//json string
                JSONArray movies = jsonResponse.getJSONArray(your json header);//в вашем случае data
                for (int i = 0; i < movies.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject actor = null;
                    actor = movies.getJSONObject(i);
                    //получили объект и теперь можем делать что хотим
                    String ID = null;
                    ID = actor.getString("ID");//you json value tag

                    News_list.add(new ArrayList<String>());
                    News_list.get(PageViewActivity.News_list.size() - 1).add(ID);

                }
```